# How to Convert String Numeric with Comma into Float in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 600x30 sized .csv file all of whose data type is string but actually numeric, such as :

> '36,000' == 36000

I'd like to convert all of those into float most efficiently.

How can I do this?

> I can think of decomposing every str-typed number using split() then erase ',' and then join then convert into float again.. but it looks too cumbersome.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 7):

Using `replace` and `pd.to_numeric`

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'val':['36,000','36,000','36,000','36,000','36,000']})

s.replace({',':''},regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric,1)
Out[76]: 
     val
0  36000
1  36000
2  36000
3  36000
4  36000
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed the pandas tag, great answer!

Comment: pd.to_numeric only available each column- which represented in as a pd.Series. How can I do this at once for entire columns - which means entire DataFrame?

Comment: @delinco that is why we have apply here , I update a little bit , `s.replace({',':''},regex=True).apply(pd.to_numeric,1)
`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Wen's answer, for a dataframe, you can use:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','').apply(pd.to_numeric))
```

Comment: what is lambda x ?

Comment: @delinco it's a python syntax to create anonymous function with x as its parameter.

Comment: It gives me error - AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index ACH')

Comment: Maybe try: df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(',','').apply(pd.to_numeric))

Comment: @delinco did u assign it back to df or a new df?